# Getting Enum type from string

Tags: c#, types, enums

What I'm trying to do is get Enum Type from string.

example:

```
//enum which can be changed I'll know only string name of it at runtime ("Color")
public enum Color
{ 
   Black,
   Green,
   Yellow
}
```

I've maked some research on google but was unable to find something which do what i need.
Anyone resolved this in past?

Comment: could you provide more code what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need [Type.GetType method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

```
public static Type GetType(
    string typeName
)
```

Comment: Thanks:) I forgot about that method :(

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
Color c = (Color) Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), "Yellow", true);
Console.WriteLine("Color Value: {0}", c.ToString());
```

**PS: use `Colors` instead of `Color`**

**[FOR REFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)**

Comment: As he stated in question, his problem is that he does not know Color at compile-time

Comment: like archil said I don't know `Color` at runtime, but thanks for trying to help:)